# How to hide data rows with certain value with a button?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I use `react-bootstrap-table-next`. And want to use a toggle button which hide or show rows with a certain value. But the problem is that the table content doesn't change.

```
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';

const products = [
  {id: 0, name: 'item 0', price: 4},
  {id: 1, name: 'item 1', price: 5},
  {id: 2, name: 'item 2', price: 3},
  {id: 3, name: 'item 3', price: 5},
]

const columns = [{
  dataField: 'id',
  text: 'Product ID'
}, {
  dataField: 'name',
  text: 'Product Name',
}, {
  dataField: 'price',
  text: 'Product Price',
}];

const handleClick = () => {
  for (i=0; i> products.length; i++) {
    if (products[i]["price"] === 5) {
      products.slice(i, 1);
    }
  }
};

export default () => (
  <div>
    <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onClick={ handleClick }>hide data </button>

    <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ products } columns={ columns } />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Hint: `useState`

Comment: Please don't insult other users or revert changes that improve posts.

Comment: I didn't want insult you! I apologize myself if you feel insulted. But I still use ``react-bootstrap-table-next`` and not ``react-bootstrap-table``!

Comment: I understand the concern, but react-bootstrap-table-next is just the npm module name due to npm conflicts; the actual plugin/product name is react-bootstrap-table2, which is just the latest version of react-bootstrap-table (since the original version was deprecated/replaced). [tag:react-bootstrap-table] refers to/covers both the original v1 plugin and the newer v2/vnext version. That aside, tag names don't belong in question titles.

Comment: @TylerH Ok. I understand why you had changed it. I totally agree with the headline change. But I think it is important to mention that I use v2/next. So I am fine with your current changes! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to update products, but on every re-render, it will reset to its initial value (***Because it's defined outside the component's function***). So, the value of products will always be the same.

One solution is to move `products` inside the component and create a state for it.

You can reshape your code like this:

```
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import { useState } from 'react';

const columns = [{
    dataField: 'id',
    text: 'Product ID'
}, {
    dataField: 'name',
    text: 'Product Name',
}, {
    dataField: 'price',
    text: 'Product Price',
}];

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([
        { id: 0, name: 'item 0', price: 4 },
        { id: 1, name: 'item 1', price: 5 },
        { id: 2, name: 'item 2', price: 3 },
        { id: 3, name: 'item 3', price: 5 },
    ]);

    const handleClick = () => {
        let temp = products;
        for (i = 0; i > temp.length; i++) {
            if (temp[i]["price"] === 5) {
                temp.slice(i, 1);
            }
        };

        setProducts(temp);
    };

    return (
        < div >
            <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onClick={handleClick}>hide data </button>

            <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={products} columns={columns} />
        </div >
    )
};

export default MyComponent;
```